# Startup.cs vs Program.cs in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I looked through the documentation on the Microsoft website and there are two places where we can set up the configuration.

We can do it either in *Startup.cs* or *Program.cs.* However, *Program.cs* has the same methods that are available in *Startup.cs*

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                //same as ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs
                services.AddAutofac();
            })
            .Configure(app =>
            {
                //same as Configure method in Startup.cs
                app.UseMvc();
            })
            .Build();
}
```

Is the only purpose for the existence of "Startup.cs" to move some of the configuration out of "Program.cs"? Could we remove this file altogether and keep the entire configuration in "Program.cs"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Could we remove this class altogether and keep entire configuration in Program.cs ?

**Yes**

Documentation explains

> ### [Convenience methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2#convenience-methods)
>
> To configure services and the request processing pipeline without using a `Startup` class, call `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` **convenience methods** on the host builder. Multiple calls to `ConfigureServices` append to one another. If multiple `Configure` method calls exist, the last `Configure` call is used.

It is more about the configuring of the builder than the actual *Program.cs*. That is just the default template class used to hold main entry to the application.

Reference [App startup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: The current version of the page linked doesn't even mention Startup.cs anymore. MS' preferred way nowadays seems to be doing all of it in Program.cs.

Answer (score 4):

Program.cs is where the application starts.

Startup.cs is where lot of the configuration happens.

The idea for this separation is based on SOLID principles' first principle- SRP (Single Responsibility Principle). [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) make software designs more understandable, flexible, and maintainable.

[Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) states that a class or a method should only do one thing (or should have only one job). If you look at the Startup.cs, it does exactly this making it easy to read and understand the code.